# Returning template argument explicitly

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a function which takes an "auto" and returns an "auto". This function takes numeric types (eg, complex, int, or doubles).  However, depending on the result of the function, I need to return something explicitly.  For example, if a complex number is passed to the function, I need to return "complex(0, 0)" if the "real" part of the number is less than zero.  The code looks something like the following:

```
if(myNumber<0){ return 0.0;} else{ return myNumber; }
```

Now of course I have to overload the "less than" operator but the difficult part is how to allow returning 0 when myNumber is not a double.  I have overloaded the "=" operator to allow assignment of doubles to complex numbers, however I still get compiling errors.

Is there any good way to accomplish this?

Edit:

My complete code looks like the following.

```
auto BSCall(const auto &S0, const auto &k, const auto &discount, const auto &sigma){ 
if(sigma<=0){
    return 0.0;
}
else{
    double s=sqrt(2.0);
    auto d1=log(S0/(discount*k))/(sigma)+sigma*.5;
    return S0*(.5+.5*erf(d1/s))-k*discount*(.5+.5*(erf((d1-sigma)/s)));  
}}
```

Edit again:

It turns out that I didn't have my class have a constructor which took a double.  My code works when I have both the operator "=" overloaded AND a constructor which has a single double.

Comment: "I have a function which takes an "auto" and returns an "auto". " That doesn't exist in C++14. Are you using the GCC extension?

Comment: Is your complex type `std::complex<double>`?

Comment: No I created my own class...I want it to be applicable to other numeric types as well.

Comment: @T.C. OP is talking about trailing return type

Comment: @AngelusMortis Doesn't sound like it. Besides, the problem is with "taking an auto", not "returning an auto".

Comment: @T.C. sorry , i was mistaken I guess

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running into issues because you have two returns that are returning different types, and the compiler can't decide which type to use as the return type.

You can get around this by putting your calculation into a helper function:

```
auto BSCallHelper(
        const auto &S0,
        const auto &k,
        const auto &discount,
        const auto &sigma
        )
{
    double s=sqrt(2.0);
    auto d1=log(S0/(discount*k))/(sigma)+sigma*.5;
    return S0*(.5+.5*erf(d1/s))-k*discount*(.5+.5*(erf((d1-sigma)/s))); 
}
```

Then you can use the helper function to make your return type be explicit:

```
auto BSCall(
        const auto &S0,
        const auto &k,
        const auto &discount,
        const auto &sigma
        ) -> decltype(BSCallHelper(S0,k,discount,sigma))
{ 
    if(sigma<=0){
        return 0.0;
    }

    return BSCallHelper(S0,k,discount,sigma);
}
```

You can also use the `?:` operator to resolve a common type:

```
auto BSCall(
        const auto &S0,
        const auto &k,
        const auto &discount,
        const auto &sigma
        )
{
    return (sigma<=0) ? 0 : BSCallHelper(S0,k,discount,sigma);
}
```

Comment: Edit: I still get the original error (could not convert ‘0.0’ from ‘double’)

Comment: @user9403: Which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc 5.2.1.

Comment: I should add that when I use doubles (like in your example) it compiles, it only doesn't compile when I use a a class instead of a primitive.

Comment: @user9403: I've added another alternative to my answer.

Comment: When I use std::complex your method does work.  I have created my own complex class and other numeric classes that aren't working.  Though looking through the std::complex documentation it appears that I've implemented it very similarly..its odd that std::complex works but my custom classes don't.

Comment: @user9403: Do you have a constructor which takes a double?

Comment: Woops!  Good catch!  That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways:

First is to try initializer list:

```
if(myNumber<0){
    return {};   //  <= it means you return T()
}else{
    return myNumber;
}
```

Second is to use `std::result_of` from [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) header.

```
if(myNumber<0){
    return std::result_of<YourFunctionReference>::type();
}else{
    return myNumber;
}
```

Of course your function is templated so I'm not quite sure if second way will work. Please post additional code from your project so I will be able to tell you how to use `std::result_of` in your case.

Comment: Auto return with the furst return being `return{};` works?